# Unslider is not behaving responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-slider

I'm trying to make a slideshow in jquery that allows responsive design. 
I have some problems first because I was using images with size  1183*235, and then the images don't occupy the full width, now im using images 1900*235 and now occupy the full width.
But when I tail off the screen, the images dont resizes.
We need to do something additional to the responsive design works with unslider?
The `fluid:true` is not enough?

This is my code working: http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/T8JdT/1/

My html:

```
<div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-image:url(imagens/image1.png)"><h2>This is a slide.</h2></li>
        <li style="background-image:url(imagens/image1.png)">This is another slide.</li>
        <li style="background-image:url(imagens/image1.png)">This is a final slide.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</section
```

My css:

```
 #banner-container{width:100%; float:left;}
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto;}
.banner li { list-style: none; background-repeat:no-repeat; }
.banner ul li { float: left; min-height:250px;}
.banner .dots { bottom: 20px; left: 0; position: absolute; right: 0;
} .banner .dots li { border: 2px solid #fff; border-radius: 6px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; height: 10px; margin: 0 4px; opacity: .4; text-indent: -999em; -webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s; -moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s; transition: background .5s, opacity .5s; width: 10px; } .banner .dots li.active { background: #fff; opacity: 1; }
```

My jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="unslider/unslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider({
        dots: true,
        speed: 650,
        delay: 2000,
        fluid: true

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was that! You know if it is possible set the width of image in this line: <li style="background-image:url(imagens/image1.png)"><h3><a rel="#">This is a slide.</a></h3></li> instead of the CSS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/T8JdT/2/ With the plugin script!

Comment: ah ok sorry, i think i understdood now! http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/T8JdT/4/

Comment: If you got the answer, please post it in 'Answer' section for other users facing similar issue.